# How to Remove Event Listener from Function

Tags: javascript, function

I am utilizing the accordion build from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp). It works great, but I would like to clean things up a bit by creating a function for this in my JS file (rather than inline `<script>` tags). The problem is that I need to tweak it a little by removing the event listener, but I have had little luck (still learning JS). How Can I achieve this?

Below is what I want to do, but need to remove the event listener because it makes the user have to double click in order to activate the accordion.

HTML:

```
<button class="accordion" onclick="faqsAccordion()">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function faqsAccordion() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("faqs-active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Gist

Keep a version of the function you're using as an event listener, e.g

```
function MyHandler(){
    console.log("clicked!");
}
document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener("click", MyHandler);
```

then you can later remove it by just using the same function name.

```
document.getElementById("MyButton").removeEventListener("click", MyHandler);
```

If you insist on using the `onclick` property, you can also set it to null manually in code; however I don't recommend it. `onclick` in HTML is confusing, it executes the code inside of the string rather than just setting the "click" event handler to the function with that name.

```
document.getElementById("MyButton").onclick = null;
```

Oddly enough, changing it to a different string doesn't work. A lot of these old HTML attributes glued to JS work in counter-intuitive ways. It doesn't work because the onclick *property* takes a function pointer and refuses anything else meanwhile the onclick *attribute* takes a string that executes.

### What you want to do

You want to turn this

```
function faqsAccordion() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("faqs-active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

Into this

```
<button class="accordion" id="faqsAccordian">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("faqsAccordian").addEventListener("click",faqsAccordian);
function myfunc(e){ // Added the "event" parameter for you, for future use :)
  this.classList.toggle("faqs-active");
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  } 
}
function faqsAccordion() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", myfunc);
  }
}
// ... some time later...
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
const whichever = 0;

// Randomly remove an event listener... muahuahua...
acc[whichever].removeEventListener("click", myfunc);
```

### However...

What if you want to use anonymous functions because you want many of the same function to act as an event listener? Let's say we want one more alert box to pop up from clicking MyButton below.

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="MyButton">Add alert to the bottom button</button><br>
<button id="MyAlertButton">Popup please!</button>

<script>
var MyAlertButtonFunctionPointers = [];
function MyAlertButtonClickWrapper(e){
    MyAlertButtonFunctionPointers.forEach(f=>f(e))
}
document.getElementById("MyAlertButton").addEventListener("click", MyAlertButtonClickWrapper);

document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  MyAlertButtonFunctionPointers.push(e=>{
    alert("Hi! I'm a button with the name " + this.id + "\nThe event that lead to me being clicked happened at (" + e.screenX + ", " + e.screenY + ")"); 
  })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then remove selectively any event listener you want by just popping it out of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused on how to implement this into my situation. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Ah sorry, misread your question. You would make that anonymous function (The one which is setting the panels height to either null or scrollHeight and toggling classlist w/ class faq-active) a named function and just add that as an event listener. When functions are called, the caller passes on their context - "this" will still yield the button object you wish to affect. Added the response as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Is this used with or without `onclick`? I put in your code and I still have to double-click to activate the accordion.

Comment: my code doesn't touch onclick; it assumes that you previously added to your first accordian button the faqsAccordian event listener. If you want individual behaviour for a certain element, I recommend giving it an id to make things simpler. If you really want you can just ```getElementsByClassName("accordian")``` and then use the index that you know that button will be in.

I updated my code to fit yours; what I wrote should be plug-and-play for you now.

Comment: I plugged in your code exactly (not the anonymous one), but its not working. The console gives this error in the JS: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: You didn't set the id of the accordian button to faqsAccordian. I added that change for a reason :) If you want individual functionality in vanilla JS, use IDs.